# Executing block of code without context switch

Tags: linux-kernel, context-switch, perf

Is there any way to execute a block of code in C without suffering a Context Switch?

I have modified perf stat to sample the counters periodically. While this works, it ends up giving me some bad data points such as 0 cycles x instructions.

I believe that the reason for this happening is because of context switching.

Since my code always pulls cycle counter value before instruction counter, if a context switch were to happen after pulling the cycle counter value, and if the process I was profiling executed for some portion of the scheduling quanta, then when I finally pulled the instruction counter value, it would be 'one ahead' of the cycle counter value that I already pulled.

Is there any way to execute the code-block without allowing a context switch to take place?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no easy way to achieve that -executing a code without context switches- (except if your code is running inside the kernel, but you want to handle interrupts anyway).

You could measure time inside a Linux application using [clock_gettime(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html). Read [time(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/time.7.html) carefully.

BTW, you do want context switches. Without them, some computers may physically get too hot and be physically broken. (Some machines handle their fans with software).

Comment: I did try to identify if there was a context switch happening by measuring time. Normally, the time taken for pulling one counter value is around 60~80ns. However, my instruction counter seems to go ahead even when the time taken from the end of cycle counter reading to the end of instruction counter reading is within this time.

Is there a way I can identify occurrence of a context switch without using time delay? (Since the delay is not large enough to confidently attribute it to context switching)